# How to seperate navigation tabs when position is fixed in css

Tags: html, css

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8/">
            <title> Jquery </title>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jsi/Scriptz.js" > </script>
           <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "RizzStyle.css"/> 
            <!-- Start Slider -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
            <!-- End Slider-->

       </head>




        <body onload = "Slider();" background = "black.jpg" >


        <div id = "header">

            <nav class = "navMain">
                <div class = "Logo">  <a href = "Main.html"> <img src = "Logo.png" border = "0" /> </a>  </div>
            <ul> 
                <li> <input type = "radio" name = "nav-group" id = "amazing" class = "navOption"> 
                <label for = "css" class = "nav-item"> Home</label>
                </li>

                <li> <input type = "radio" name = "nav-group" id = "css" class = "navOption"> 
                <label for = "css" class = "nav-item"> Sign In</label>
                </li>


                <li> <input type = "radio" name = "nav-group" id = "dropdown" class = "navOption"> 
                <label for = "css" class = "nav-item"> About Us</label>
                </li>


            </ul>        

            </nav>

        </div>



            <div id = "container" > 


                <div id="wowslider-container1">
                    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
              <li><img src="data1/images/north.jpg" alt="North" title="North" id="wows1_0"/></li>
              <li><a href="http://wowslider.com/vi"><img src="data1/images/wolf.jpg" alt="content slider" title="Wolf" id="wows1_1"/></a>             </li>
            <li><img src="data1/images/android.jpg" alt="Android" title="Android" id="wows1_2"/></li>
           </ul></div>
           <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
              <a href="#" title="North"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/north.jpg" alt="North"/>1</span></a>
              <a href="#" title="Wolf"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/wolf.jpg" alt="Wolf"/>2</span></a>
              <a href="#" title="Android"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/android.jpg" alt="Android"/>3</span></a>
           </div></div>
        <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
                </div>  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>


                <div class = "shadow">

                </div>


            </div>

        </body>



    </html>





#container {
               width:1200px;
               height:1000px;
               margin: 70px auto;
               border : 1px solid;
               background-color: aliceblue;

           }




  #header{
            width : 100%;
            height: 60px;
            background-color:#212121;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #333; 
            position:fixed; 
            top:0px;
            z-index: 1000;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }


  #header h1{
            width : 1024px;
            margin : 0px auto; 
            padding:12px;
            color:white; 

        }





.shadow{
    background-image : url(shadow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    width: 864px;
    height:144px;
    margin: -60px auto;


}

.Logo{

    float:left;
    height: 60px;
    padding:5px 3px;
    line-height:40px;

}

.Logo img{
    width:60%;
}



.navMain{

    width:100%;
    background-color:#212121;
    height:70px;
    color:aliceblue;


}


.navMain ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;

}


.navMain> ul > li{
    float:left;


}

.nav-item{

    display:inline-block;
    padding: 15px 50px ;
    height:41px;
    margin:0;
    line-height:40px;
    margin-left:120px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position:fixed;

}


.nav-item:hover{
    background-color:#FF0000;
    cursor:pointer;


}

.navOption{
    display:none;


}
```

Hello People so recently i have been trying to create a website. The issue is when I resize my web browser page the header tabs all muddle up so I set the header class position to fixed and all the tabs just join together forming a weird looking thing which is supposed to be seperated in three tabs instead joined together.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest setting header to `position: relative` and add a `min-width : '800px'`  <- example , you can make the min width whatever you like.

Also as you go on developing you will realize the need for a fluid design in which case I recommend looking into CSS media queries.

With position fixed you need to define where in the view able browser you want to display the header.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes now when I resize the page it doesnt muddle the tabs but it did create a gap between the container and the header also when I resize the page the tabs all go down instead of staying in the header position. is there anyway I can fix that?

Comment: try getting rid of margins and padding on the elements. by 'tabs going down' do you mean they go from a horizontal list to a vertical list. i think your issue is you are adding the `display : inline-block` on the label tag when it should be on the `<li>` tag.

Comment: Yes as I make the screen smaller it goes from horizontal to vertical tried putting display-in-line-block in the li tab still no progress however when I use your initial method it stays horizontal but goes below the header section-in the gap between header and container. The gap was made when I set position: relative and min-width : 70px;

Comment: Actually sorry It does go vertical the font was white camouflaging the tab to container so I assumed it was in the side

Comment: Get rid of the floats, floating the nav can cause what you are describing. Why are you floating your nav?

Comment: Good question ? erm lol im new to developing as I am a SE student( first year) anyway I removed the paddings and when I remove the margins from nav Items it just messes up even more. This is so annoying :( Thankyou very much for helping though

Comment: Actually no worries I just had to add white-space: nowrap;, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `fixed`  property on each individual nav-item. Instead, use it on the on the entire nav.

```
.navMain{
width:100%;
background-color:#212121;
height:70px;
color:aliceblue;
position: fixed;
}

.nav-item{
display:inline-block;
padding: 15px 50px ;
height:41px;
margin:0;
line-height:40px;
margin-left:120px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still same thing :(

Comment: try putting the fixed position  it on header instead of navMain, to be honest. i believe the problem is that all of them are getting fixed to the same position.

Comment: Its all good I just included   white-space: nowrap;
  in the header and it works